# Avoiding unwanted reflexions

Tags: reflection

You guys always solve my issues. This one I can't wrap my head around and I will really benefit from some direction. I am rendering this scene here:
[image]

As you can see all the lights show up in the reflexion of the eyes, I want to get rid of them. So I follow what is recommended, I go to the light settings and turn off Ray Visibility Glossy. It does get rid of the lights in the reflexion but in the process I lose the nice rim light in the hair because Glossy does affect the hair too. Is there a way to turn off it off without losing the those lighting qualities.
[image]

Comment: Interesting... turning off glossy for the balloons only stops it from showing up in other reflections, and turning off glossy for the lights messes up the hair... The only things I can think of is to either try creating objects to be directly in the path of the light to block the reflections or to render it twice and photoshop it. Personally, I actually like the light reflections on the balloons, makes the eyes cuter.

Comment: It is strange right? If I add objects in front, they will probably stop the light from hitting and I will have the same issue no?   I 100% agree about the eye highlights I just want to control it myself instead of creating them from the actual lights. I generally use 2 spheres to create them exactly how I want them...

Comment: Maybe there's some way to work around this using render layers, but in my opinion it would be easier to resort to rendering it twice and compositing in photoshop (if it's a still image).